# FFMPEG zoompan image is cut off

Tags: ffmpeg, zooming, overlay

Hi I'm using zoompan to resize an image overlay on a video using ffmpeg, but my image got cut off by the boundary after setting its size, like the following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 6.mp4 -loop 1 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1:v]zoompan=z=2:d=50:x=0:y=0:s='280x105'[1v];[0:v][1v]overlay=x=0:y=0" -t 8 test.mp4
```

[image]

If I remove the size, it becomes really big covering all screen, like following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 6.mp4 -loop 1 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1:v]zoompan=z=2:d=50:x=0:y=0[1v];[0:v][1v]overlay=x=0:y=0" -t 8 test.mp4
```

[image]

How do we zoom an overlay image while scaling its size?

Comment: Do you just want a static resized logo, for overlaying?

Comment: I nid to animate the image size using zoomspan. Or is there better way we can animate the size without zoompan?

Comment: From full size to small size?

Comment: both~ from full to small and small to full